# изображения laravel + vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

при npm run dev выдает ошибку на изображение

```
 @ ./resources/assets/js/components/pages/shop/Shop.vue 6:23-272
 @ ./resources/assets/js/shopRoute.js
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
```

код компонента

```
                       <div class=col-md-3">
                            <div class="product-item">
                                <div class="product__item-image">
                                    <img src="/img/product/p1.jpg" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="product__item-body">
                                    <p class="product-item__title">Alstr Estee</p>
                                    <div class="product-item__price">
                                        <span class="current">€</span>
                                        <span class="price">0.22</span>
                                        <div class="opt-price">
                                            <span class="count">≥ 10 шт: <span class="opt__price">0.24</span></span>
                                            <span class="count">
                            ≥ 10 шт:
                            <span class="opt__price">0.22</span>
                        </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="flover__specifications">
                                        <li>Кол-во мест<span>3</span></li>
                                        <li>Содержание<span>8</span></li>
                                        <li>Количество<span>220</span></li>
                                        <li>Код тары<span>998</span></li>
                                        <li>Шт. в пучке<span>10</span></li>
                                        <li>Длина стебля<span>75cm</span></li>
                                        <li>Вес (средний)<span>85gr</span></li>
                                        <li>Количество бутонов<span>minimaal 5</span></li>
                                        <li>Стадия зрелости<span>2-3</span></li>
                                        <li>Страна происхождения<span>NL</span></li>
                                        <li>Качество<span>A1</span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="product__footer">
                                        Садовник <span class="gardener">Onno Dobbe - NL</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас синтаксическая ошибка. В первом же `div` нет открывающей строки в атрибуте `class`:

```
<div class=col-md-3"> <-- вот тут добавьте перед col "
  <div class="product-item">
```